# How to add a FileTransport cleanly to Asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm writing an application which reads text data and acts on it. The text data could come from a TCP port, or from a text file (which contains data earlier read from the TCP port and archived). I'm writing it in Python 3, and using [**asyncio**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) seems like the obvious tool to use.

It's straightforward to use the [Streams API `open_connection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#stream-functions) to open the TCP port and read from it. The **asyncio** architecture has the concept a [Transport](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#transports) and a [Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#protocols) for the lower and upper layers of input-output. So, it seems I should implement a Transport for reading text from a file, and pass it to the Protocol. That will let me keep the rest of my application decoupled from whether the text data came from the TCP port or the file.

But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to tell **asyncio** to use my preferred Transport.

- the [Streams API `open_connection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#stream-functions) has a parameter list which is all about the TCP port Transport, with no way to specify a different Transport, much less parameters like file path.
- `open_connection()` turns around and calls [`loop.create_connection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#creating-connections). This is just as specialised for the TCP Port Transport. Still now way to provide a different Transport.
- The implementation of `loop.create_connection()` gets its Transport object from either `self._make_ssl_transport()` or `self._make_socket_transport()`. These have alternative implementations in `asyncio.selector_events.BaseSelectorEventLoop` and `asyncio.proactor_events.BaseProactorEventLoop`, so we are clearly past the point where a File Transport ought to have been selected.

Am I missing some place where **asyncio** lets me tell it what Transport to use?  Or is **asyncio** really coded down to its roots to use its own TCP port and UDP datagram Transports, and nothing else?

If I want to allow the possibility of using my own Transport with **asyncio**, it looks like I have to extend the event loop, or write more a flexible alternative `create_connection()` that is coded to a particular event loop implementation.  That seems like a lot of work, and vulnerable to changes in the implementation.

Or, is it a foolish errand to handle file input with a Transport?  Should I instead structure my code to say:

`if (using_tcp_port): 
    await asyncio.open_connection(....)
else:
    completely_different_file_implementation(....)`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_connection) of **API** `create_connection()`, it *takes* a protocol and *creates* a **streaming** transport, which *is* a TCP connection. So it is not supposed to be an API for custom transports.

However, the idea to reuse the same protocol for either TCP transports or custom file transports is valid. It won't be a "completely different implementation", but at least not using `create_connection()`. Let's assume it is `read_file()`:

```
def my_protocol_factory():
    return your_protocol

if using_tcp_port:
    transport, protocol = await loop.create_connection(my_protocol_factory, host, port)
else:
    transport, protocol = await read_file(loop, my_protocol_factory, path_to_file)
```

Then you would have something like this:

```
from asyncio import transports

import aiofiles  # https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles


def read_file(loop, protocol_factory, path):
    protocol = protocol_factory()
    transport = FileTransport(path, loop)
    transport.set_protocol(protocol)
    return transport, protocol


class FileTransport(transports.ReadTransport):
    def __init__(self, path, loop):
        super().__init__()
        self._path = path
        self._loop = loop
        self._closing = False

    def is_closing(self):
        return self._closing

    def close(self):
        self._closing = True

    def set_protocol(self, protocol):
        self._protocol = protocol
        self._loop.create_task(self._do_read())

    def get_protocol(self):
        return self._protocol

    async def _do_read(self):
        try:
            async with aiofiles.open(self._path) as f:
                self._loop.call_soon(self._protocol.connection_made, self)
                async for line in f:
                    self._loop.call_soon(self._protocol.data_received, line)
                    if self._closing:
                        break
                self._loop.call_soon(self._protocol.eof_received)
        except Exception as ex:
            self._loop.call_soon(self._protocol.connection_lost, ex)
        else:
            self._loop.call_soon(self._protocol.connection_lost, None)
```

Comment: No problem, it's a library that calls blocking file I/O in thread pool (executor).

Comment: At the risk of turning this into a discussion: the statement, "a streaming transport, which is a TCP connection", is not self-evident. I interpret "stream" to mean an abstraction of input/output as a sequence of bytes, which could be attached to TCP connections, files, the Unix stdin/stdout/stderror, or pipes to Unix filters, or a wide range of things. I think <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams> has the same broad meaning. If the `asyncio` package wants to define "streams" as limited to TCP connections, they should say so.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt Oh I should have said "`create_connection()` ... creates a streaming transport, which is a TCP connection **in this case**". I agree with you that stream is more generic than just TCP. And actually `create_connection()` may also be used to create UNIX domain sockets, by passing in a `sock` instance initialized with `AF_UNIX`, it is just not a traditional usage though with `create_unix_connection()` present. The implication in this documentation is: it is creating a streaming transport with **socket**.

Comment: Actually neither [socket(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) nor [connect(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) mentioned TCP, and `create_connection()` has claimed to use `AF_INET`/`AF_INET6` and `SOCK_STREAM` to connect to Internet host and port.